# ScrollTo() in Javascript scrolls all down

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML Document I've got a input field. You can give in a number and the window should scroll down to this pixel number.

I've used the `scrollTo()` function. The thing is, that it always scrolls to the bottom of the page.

If I type `window.scrollTo(0, 500 + 400);` it works fine, but with `window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById("field").value + 400);` it always scrolls all the way down.

You can see the problem in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ultraphilipp/eusq986j/

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

First you're using the wrong field ID. Use 'depth' instead.

The second problem is that

```
document.getElementById("depth").value
```

returns a **string**

Let's say you input the number 5.

What it does, is "5" + 400 = 5400

To fix this, you have to convert the value to an **integer**

```
window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(document.getElementById("depth").value) + 400);
```

Should fix your problem.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Didn't know that I get a string from that. Thanks for the explanation, you helped me very much with this!

Answer (score 0):

You've used wrong field ID, instead of `field` you have to use `depth`. Check correct code below:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById("depth").value + 400);
```

Comment: Little mistake while I created the fiddle. But it also doesn't work with the correct ID: https://jsfiddle.net/ultraphilipp/eusq986j/1/

Comment: Is new link updated, I'm unable to see updated field name. And as per @timon mentioned you also need to do parseInt().

Comment: I changed the name in the javascript. It worked with the solution from Timon, but thank you very much for your help.